# Use of pattern in hook_theme()

Tags: theming

I'm trying to implement pattern but It doesn't work.
Here is the implementation of hook_theme() with my pattern:

Call `theme('publication__' . 'news', array('bean' => $bean));`

in file atom_publications.module

```
function atom_publications_theme() {
  return array(
    'publication' => array(
      'variables' => array('bean' => NULL),
      'pattern' => 'publication__',
      'file' => 'atom_publications.theme.inc',
      'preprocess functions' => array('atom_publication_custom_preprocess'),
      'template' => 'publication',
    ),
  );
}
```

In file atom_publications.theme.inc write this code:

```
function atom_publication_custom_preprocess(&$variables) {
}
```

Files in module dir:

- publication.tpl.php
- publication--news.tpl.php

But render only publication.tpl.php template. Why?

Comment: `pattern` should be a regular expression - therefore the pattern of `publication__` won't match `publication__news`.  I'm *guessing* it should be more like `publication__([^\s]+)` to match any word, but my regex is mega rusty, so please check it first (hence me not adding this as an answer).

Comment: See the example reported in [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7): "For example, to allow forums to be themed individually, the pattern might be 'forum__'. Then, when the forum is themed, call `theme(array('forum__' . $tid, 'forum'), $forum)`." Unfortunately, `theme()` is not using that property in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7), I notice that the "pattern" property is never used. What the function does is using the following code.

```
  // If there's no implementation, check for more generic fallbacks. If there's
  // still no implementation, log an error and return an empty string.
  if (!isset($hooks[$hook])) {
    // Iteratively strip everything after the last '__' delimiter, until an
    // implementation is found.
    while ($pos = strrpos($hook, '__')) {
      $hook = substr($hook, 0, $pos);
      if (isset($hooks[$hook])) {
        break;
      }
    }
```

In your case, `theme()` first looks for `publication__news` key in theme functions array, and then it looks for the `publication` key. As in your case there isn't any match for `publication__news`, it uses `publication`, and the template file associated with that theme function.

This is documented in [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7).

> If the name contains a double-underscore (`__`) and there isn't an implementation for the full name, the part before the `__` is checked. This allows a fallback to a more generic implementation. For example, if `theme('links__node', ...)` is called, but there is no implementation of that theme hook, then the 'links' implementation is used. This process is iterative, so if `theme('links__contextual__node', ...)` is called, `theme()` checks for the following implementations, and uses the first one that exists:
>
> - `links__contextual__node`
> - `links__contextual`
> - `links`
>
> This allows themes to create specific theme implementations for named objects and contexts of otherwise generic theme hooks.

Comment: `hook_theme()` does use `#pattern` [source](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7).  I can't provide an answer right away thoguh as it's a REGEX issue, and my regular expressions are pretty rusty.

Comment: It's `pattern`. The function that is used to call theme functions ([theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7)) doesn't use that property, though.

Comment: Yeah, but in the example of `theme('publication__' . 'news'...` the wrong template would be called, as the regex is incorrect in the `hook_theme()` implementation?

Comment: publication.tpl.php is being used because there aren't any module that defines `publication__news` as theme function. To use a template, `theme()` first looks for a theme function matching the given name; then, it uses the template file associated with the found theme function.

Comment: This is the case unless `pattern` is used, in which case the theme implemention can be dynamic.

Comment: **pattern**: A regular expression pattern to be used to allow this theme implementation to have a dynamic name. The convention is to use __ to differentiate the dynamic portion of the theme.

Comment: May you point out the code that in `theme()` would use the "pattern" property? Drupal 7 is not using that property. [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) documents it, but [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7) is not actually using it.

Comment: Hmm..that's odd.  Maybe it's documented but deprecated - I'm sure I've used it in D7 sites though!  I'll have to have a better look and then perhaps put it as a Community wiki - apologies Kia :)

Comment: After reading this I assumed that the `pattern` was indeed not used. However it is used in `drupal_find_theme_functions()` https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/drupal_find_theme_functions/7 called from `phptemplate_theme()`. So I suppose it is possible, I don't know how though...

Comment: @Neograph734 Good catch! Yes, that function uses it, if "base hook" is not defined. It is just to see if `theme()` calls `phptemplate_theme()`. I will check in the next 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same situation and couldn't figure what went wrong. If I look at the Views module, there are patterns defined, and when I place a file called `views_view_field__<fieldname>.tpl.php` in my theme folder it works.

So I tried to move the theme override file from the module folder to the theme folder. It worked there.

The problem is that the *.tpl.php files should not be in the module folder. Only the theme folder is scanned for the pattern. (Making it impossible to define several sub-templates in a module).

Also the pattern should  contain underscores, where the template uses dashes:

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'entity_name' => array(
      'render element' => 'elements', 
      'path' => $path . '/theme',
      'file' => 'mymodule.theme.inc',
      'template' => 'entity-name',
      'pattern' => 'entity_name__',
    ),
  ),
}
```

In order to define other options at module level, you should include all of them in hook theme:

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'entity_name' => array(
      'render element' => 'elements', 
      'path' => $path . '/theme',
      'file' => 'mymodule.theme.inc',
      'template' => 'entity-name',
      'pattern' => 'entity_name__',
    ),
    'entity_name__variation' => array(
      'render element' => 'elements', 
      'path' => $path . '/theme',
      'file' => 'mymodule.theme.inc',
      'template' => 'entity-name--variation',
    ),
  ),
}
```

Defining the pattern again is not be necessary, and now it works from both the module folder (for your own alterations) and the theme folder (for the end-user's alterations).

Answer (score 0):

You have to place your templalte file (publication--news.tpl.php) in your theme directory.

Best,